# How to encode empty string using BERT

Tags: string, spacy, tokenize, bert-language-model

I have recently been trying to encode an empty string with CamemBERT (BERT model for French). I wasn't sure on how to do that. If I try to simply encode an empty string,

```
from transformers import CamembertModel, CamembertTokenizer
import torch
tokenizer = CamembertTokenizer.from_pretrained("camembert-base")
camembert = CamembertModel.from_pretrained("camembert-base")
tokenized_sentence = tokenizer.tokenize("")
encoded_sentence = tokenizer.encode(tokenized_sentence, return_tensors='pt')
embeddings = camembert(encoded_sentence)
embeddings.last_hidden_state.squeeze()[0] # embedding of the CLS token
```

I get the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-553400f369a8> in <module>
      1 # Tokenize in sub-words with SentencePiece
      2 tokenized_sentence = tokenizer.tokenize("")
----> 3 encoded_sentence = tokenizer.encode(tokenized_sentence, return_tensors='pt')
      4 embeddings = camembert(encoded_sentence)
      5 embeddings.last_hidden_state.squeeze()[0] # embeddings.last_hidden_state[0][0]

~/anaconda3/envs/r_nlp2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in encode(self, text, text_pair, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, stride, return_tensors, **kwargs)
   2057                 ``convert_tokens_to_ids`` method).
   2058         """
-> 2059         encoded_inputs = self.encode_plus(
   2060             text,
   2061             text_pair=text_pair,

~/anaconda3/envs/r_nlp2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in encode_plus(self, text, text_pair, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, stride, is_split_into_words, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs)
   2376         )
   2377 
-> 2378         return self._encode_plus(
   2379             text=text,
   2380             text_pair=text_pair,

~/anaconda3/envs/r_nlp2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils.py in _encode_plus(self, text, text_pair, add_special_tokens, padding_strategy, truncation_strategy, max_length, stride, is_split_into_words, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs)
    459             )
    460 
--> 461         first_ids = get_input_ids(text)
    462         second_ids = get_input_ids(text_pair) if text_pair is not None else None
    463 

~/anaconda3/envs/r_nlp2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils.py in get_input_ids(text)
    446                     )
    447                 else:
--> 448                     raise ValueError(
    449                         f"Input {text} is not valid. Should be a string, a list/tuple of strings or a list/tuple of integers."
    450                     )

ValueError: Input [] is not valid. Should be a string, a list/tuple of strings or a list/tuple of integers.
```

Which I think is expected behavior. I have tried with spaCy's French transformer model but have also been unsuccessful. Here's the code I used for spaCy :

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
import spacy
#!python -m spacy download fr_dep_news_trf
trf_fr = spacy.load("fr_dep_news_trf")
example = trf_fr("")
example._.trf_data.tensors[1].flatten() # embedding of the CLS token
```

And the error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-c53de04d2e6f> in <module>
      1 example = trf_fr("")
----> 2 example._.trf_data.tensors[1].flatten()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

simply because the model returns [].

I guess that at this point, my question is theoretical: what would be the best or a good way to encode an empty string using CamemBERT or spaCy? Would "forcing" the model to return a vector of 0 be a good thing? Would returning "impossible" values such as a (10,..., 10) be a good possibility? Should I force the tokenizer to create a sequence of [PAD] tokens? In this case, how would I implement that using spaCy and/or CamemBERT?

Thanks!

PS : I'm using

- Python 3.8.10
- spaCy 3.0.6
- transformers 4.6.1

Comment: `spacy-transformers` has some special cases / shortcuts to handle empty docs, so the `trf_data` output will be empty.

Comment: What's best completely depends on your application. I suspect in most cases the right thing is to just ignore empty inputs.

Comment: @polm23 In my case I can't remove the empty inputs. The text is in a dataset (each row has a bunch of variables, and a text variable), and removing the input would imply removing all the information included in that row from the dataset, which isn't what I want.

Comment: Oh, I guess you're combining Transformers features with something else? In that case all zeros is probably fine. Regardless you shouldn't expect the Transformers model to handle this, you should note the empty string and provide a filler value.

Comment: Yes! My goal is to use the embeddings in a statistical model. I also think using all zeros is the way to go, since I think I don't want the empty strings to have any impact on the model. Thanks for your input!